# Input Text CSS Override without !important

Tags: html, css

How can I override the CSS on the `input[type=text]` selector without using `!important`?

```
input[type=text]{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/*This doesn't work */
.bb-input{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input.bb-input` would do. The attribute selector and class selector have the same specifity. The type selector is adding additional specificity to the first selector.

Comment: Perfect! just what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

The first selector is more specific then the second:

[CSS Specifity](http://idiallo.com/blog/css-cascading-and-specicifity) **Disclaimer: This is my blog**

the class and the attribute have the same weight. The problem is that the first selector `input[type="text"]` also has the input element, which makes it more specific.

one way you can solve it is by renaming your second selector to

```
input.bb-input {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inline styling has highest priority so use inline styling

```
<input type="text" style="background-color: yellow;">
```

it will override external if no   `!important` is used

Comment: Not a great solution if the code contains 20 `input` tags.

Comment: ya generally when 20 inputs are used. we use server side scripting to generate inputs then  we can apply inline styling because  we only have to write once in script @mbnyc